# Styling an exterior border on form inputs

Tags: css

I'm hoping somebody can help me answer this, as hours of Googling is not proving fruitful. I currently have this code styling my form labels:

```
label {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 15px;
    width: 350px;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

I would like to style the same border-top property to my input, textarea and select tags. However, styling border-top on these elements styles the obvious, the border around the element itself. I would like to know if its possible to display the border outside, or if I need to use other properties to achieve my desired result.

Comment: @Adrift You cannot have outline on one side

Comment: I had looked at outline alright, it didn't seem to answer my question.

Comment: Have you tryed :before ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. Is this what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/8wmDs/ ? I have reset the border with `border: 0 none` and then applied only a top border to those elements using `border-top: 1px solid black`.

Comment: @tw16 It's not quite what I'm trying to achieve...the styled label displays a border-top at a width of 5px from the text. I would like this border-top style to continue onto my input elements, without have to wrap everything in a containing div (as this would mean hours of repetitive coding). The form has its labels and input elements display horizontally beside each other.
TiagoCésarOliveira - no, I haven't tried before, I'm not too current on CSS3.

Comment: So like this http://jsfiddle.net/8wmDs/2/ then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a border outside the elements, you will need a block element around each of the `input`, `textarea` or `select` (probably `div` if no element is semantically relevant). These blocks will receive the border and you can adjust the distance between the form elements and the border with `padding-top` on the `div`

This also has the advantage that `border` on `div` is way better supported than `border` on form elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that the borders look inset than you need simply

```
input {
   border: 0;
   border-top: 1px solid #333;
}
```

And if you literally means OUTSIDE so you can use something like shadow to spoof

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AwKyN/)

CSS

```
input {
    box-shadow: 0px -1px 1px -1px #333;
    border: none;
    margin: 50px;
}
```